# UserWarning: Argument interpolation should be of type InterpolationMode instead of int. Please, use InterpolationMode enum

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, torch, torchvision

I'm trying to run 'ConvNeXt' in my computer,the code is from https://github.com/facebookresearch/ConvNeXt 
My Pillow version is 8.0.0 ,when torch version is 1.8.0+cu111 and torchvision version is 0.9.0+cu111 
but when I run below code in terminal: 

python run_with_submitit.py --nodes 4 --ngpus 8 
--model convnext_tiny --drop_path 0.1 
--batch_size 128 --lr 4e-3 --update_freq 1 
--model_ema true --model_ema_eval true 
--data_path /path/to/imagenet-1k 
--job_dir /path/to/save_results 

there is warning
warnings.warn(
/home/username/anaconda3/envs/ConvNeXt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/functional.py:364: UserWarning: Argument interpolation should be of type InterpolationMode instead of int. Please, use InterpolationMode enum. 

I have checked online it seems to be Pillow's version and torchvision's version unfit. 
It's useless when I update my Pillow version to 9.1.0 

Thank you very much in advanced!!

Comment: Update your `torchvision` and `torch` version.
My Pillow version is 9.0.1 ,when torch version is 1.11.0
 and torchvision version is 0.12.0.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was having similar error with either

> `torchvision.transforms.Resize(size,  PIL.Image.Resampling.BILINEAR)` or
> `torchvision.transforms.Resize(size,  PIL.Image.BILINEAR)`
> (note without the **Resampling**, you would get *DeprecationWarning: BILINEAR is deprecated  Use Resampling.BILINEAR instead*

Resolved it with: `torchvision.transforms.InterpolationMode.BILINEAR`

See [documentation @ pytorch.org](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/_modules/torchvision/transforms/functional.html)